# Isolating coastal grids using convolving window (python)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy

I'm trying to isolate coastal grids from a dataset. I am able to do it by individually checking each neighbor of a land grid, and if one of the 8 neighbors is an ocean grid, then I'm saving the grid. Here's the function I've written:

```
def coastalGrids(ds):
grid=~out[0,:,:].mask #out is a 3D masked array (time,lat,lon)

#At each grid where there is land, check all its 8 neighbors, 
#and if any of them are ocean, save the grid to the dataset
coastline=np.zeros(grid.shape, dtype=bool)
for i in range(1,len(lat)-1):
    for j in range(1,len(lon)-1):
        if grid[i,j]==True:
            if (grid[i+1,j+1]!=True):
                coastline[i,j]= grid[i,j]
            elif (grid[i+1,j]!=True):
                coastline[i,j]= grid[i,j]
            elif (grid[i+1,j-1]!=True):
                coastline[i,j]= grid[i,j]
            elif (grid[i,j+1]!=True):
                coastline[i,j]= grid[i,j]
            elif (grid[i,j-1]!=True):
                coastline[i,j]= grid[i,j]
            elif (grid[i-1,j+1]!=True):
                coastline[i,j]= grid[i,j]
            elif (grid[i-1,j]!=True):
                coastline[i,j]= grid[i,j]
            elif (grid[i-1,j-1]!=True):
                coastline[i,j]= grid[i,j]
return coastline
```

I wish to know if:

1. There is a less ugly way of doing this, say using scipy's convolving windows functions?
2. Extending such function, is there a way to isolate land grids by a radius of say 10 grids from the coastline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using Image Morphology Operators

What you're currently doing is equivalent to the difference between the original boolean array and its [binary erosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_%28morphology%29).

This is closely related to the [morphological gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_gradient), but it's a slightly different definition.

At any rate, let's say we have a very simple island:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y, x = np.mgrid[-10:10:20j, -10:10:20j]
land = np.hypot(x, y) < 7

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(land, cmap='gray', edgecolor='gray', antialiased=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

We can calculate the coastline as you've defined it by eroding the island:

```
import scipy.ndimage
erosion = scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion(land)
```

[image]

And then seeing where there are any differences:

```
coast = land != erosion
```

[image]

---

### Square vs. Diagonal Connectivity

By default, this uses "square" connectivity.  In other words, it doesn't count diagonals as touching.  The default structure (a.k.a. "footprint") looks like:

```
[[0, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 0]]
```

In your code, you're assuming diagonals are touching.  In that case, you want "full" connectivity, and a structure that looks like:

```
[[1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1]]
```

To do that, we'd specify something similar to:

```
erosion = scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion(land, structure=np.ones((3,3)))
```

As a complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.ndimage

y, x = np.mgrid[-10:10:20j, -10:10:20j]
land = np.hypot(x, y) < 7

erosion = scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion(land, structure=np.ones((3,3)))
coast = land != erosion

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(coast, cmap='gray', edgecolor='gray', antialiased=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Using a Morphological Gradient

You might also consider using the morphological gradient operator.  It's the difference between the binary dilation and the binary erosion for a given input and connectivity footprint.

In your case, it would also include the sea pixels that border land, as well as the land pixels that border sea. Effectively, it will give you thicker borders.

As an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.ndimage

y, x = np.mgrid[-10:10:20j, -10:10:20j]
land = np.hypot(x, y) < 7

coast = scipy.ndimage.morphological_gradient(land,
                                            footprint=[[0, 1, 0],
                                                       [1, 1, 1],
                                                       [0, 1, 0]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(coast, cmap='gray', edgecolor='gray', antialiased=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Joe, not only for providing a perfect solution to my question, but also for introducing me to this field of mathematical morphology. Increasing the 'structure' window in the scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion() function, addressed my second query as well (of isolating inland grids to a certain radius from the coastline)!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about scipy's convolve functionality, but a version of the above that is a bit terser is to loop over the displacement indexes:

```
neighbours = [(1,1), (1,0), (1,-1), (0,1),
              (0,1), (-1,1), (-1, 0), (-1,-1)]
for i in range(1,len(lat)-1):
    for j in range(1,len(lon)-1):
        if grid[i,j]==True:
            for (di, dj) in neighbours:
                if (grid[i+di,j+dj] != True:
                    coastline[i,j]= grid[i,j]
                    break
```