# Store vertices of Polygons from Binary Image in an array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scipy, polygon

I want to extract ordered polygons representing the coastline from binary-data (1 for land, 0 for water). The goal is to describe the coastline of a polygon by getting an array beginning in Point A and returning to Point A.

Binary Data
[image]

I followed the approach using `scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion`, described here:

[Isolating coastal grids using convolving window (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771798/isolating-coastal-grids-using-convolving-window-python)

The result is a boolean matrix:
[image: Binary Data]

To extract the points, I used the boolean Matrix on a meshgrid out of Longitude and Latitude Arrays:

```
# Get Coastline
erosion = scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion(waterlevel)
coast = waterlevel != erosion

# Read out Coastline-Points
m_lon, m_lat = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)
coastline_points = np.dstack((m_lon[coast],m_lat[coast]))
```

The part, where I got stuck is to extraxt the points in an ordered way, where the polygons are extracted.
My approach works like I expect, but it is obvious that it will connect the different polygons.

```
def distance(point, array1, array2):
    dist = (point[0]-array1[:])**2 + (point[1]-array2[:])**2
    return np.argmin(dist)

def sort_it(start,array1,array2):
   queue      = [start]
   result     = []
   
   while  array1.size > 0:
      point  = queue.pop(0)
      idx = distance(point,array1,array2) 
      queue.append((array1[idx],array2[idx]))
      result.append(point)
      array1 = array1[np.arange(len(array1))!=idx]
      array2 = array2[np.arange(len(array2))!=idx]

return result
```

[image]

So how can I extract the polygons right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to extract the perimiter of the "islands" in the "river"?  I'm not sure what output format you expect.

Comment: You're almost certainly going to need some sort of clustering algorithm.  Which one to use is probably more a question for the [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.  If you really want to reduce them to polygons you'll also probably need some sort of [Hough Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform)

Comment: I was thinking of maybe a dictionary, where key = island1.. stores an 2d-array (lat,lon) where you start in point A move along (for example clockwise) the coastline and end at point A. Repeat this for every island and the coastline..

Comment: Did you try do work connected component by connected component? see for example [scipy.ndimage.measurements.label](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html#scipy.ndimage.measurements.label) to label the connected components

Comment: Added `opencv` tag as there are apparently methods to do this in that package (`cv.findContours` and `cv.approxPolyDP`), but I'm not qualified to give much of an answer.